# How can I use multiple cookies to access a site using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, bots

I am having issues working with mutilpe cookies on python selenium. I logged in to the site and after that, I downloaded the cookies in Json using puppeteer cookie extension.

I was able to use selenium to login successfully using the downloaded cookie. But I noticed something, if i log the use out from the browser, the cookies on my selenium will stop working. Thats it to say, it won't login again.

My aim is to be able to get different users cookies and have them in json, then login to them different using selenium.

Its very possible as i have a friend who has done it, but he won't teach me or tell me the process he took. Please if you know anything about it kindly help me out or you know anything I'm to learn, still go ahead. I'm using selenium in python for the operation. Thank you.